# Connecting in Liverpool on separate tickets with carry-on only

Tags: transit, connecting-flights, liverpool

I'm flying from `A->B->C` with two different companies and separate tickets. I only have a hand luggage, so I will not need to collect and check in a luggage. `A` and `B` are not Schengen, while `C` is. In airport B, Liverpool, there is only one terminal.

When I land at Liverpool, do I have to leave the transit area and go through the security checks again?

With luggage checked-in I would need to go out, collect, check-in again, and pass through security controls. However, it's not clear to me if this also applies with just a carry-on luggage.

Comment: Really depends on the airport `B` and the airlines involved.

Comment: Some airports have transit areas, some don't. Some require international travel to go through additional security, some don't. It does depend. Not familiar with Liverpool specifically, but from my experience in LHR you do go through security even on transit connections.

Comment: It depends on B if “airside” transit is possible at all (some airports do not have any provision for it, including relatively large ones such as Stansted or Luton), but even if airside transit exists, there are many cases where you will have to go through security again, depending on whether the local authority “trusts” the one for the country you are arriving from, so it also depends on A.

Comment: There does not seem to be a single word about transit or connections on the airport’s website, so chances are quite there are any provisions for it…

Comment: Oh actually they state it’s explicitly not possible: https://liverpoolairport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/209487745-I-have-a-connecting-flight-do-I-have-to-go-through-security-again-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Liverpool airport does not have any facilities for airside transit.

From https://liverpoolairport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/209487745-I-have-a-connecting-flight-do-I-have-to-go-through-security-again- :

> ## I have a connecting flight, do I have to go through security again?
>
> If you are arriving on a flight into LJLA and are departing again on another flight you will need to exit through the arrivals area and proceed to security again for your departing flight.
>
> Liverpool John Lennon Airport recommend that passengers arrive at least 2 hours prior to their scheduled time of departure.

That last part is probably quite optimistic. You should have much more buffer between the two flights.